# Find out when a variable is changed in emacs

Tags: variables, emacs

I'm using Doom Emacs, and I have the following line in my `config.el` file.

```
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

The value of `truncate-lines` is indeed `t` when I'm in an `el` file. However, when I open an `org` file, the value of `truncate-lines` is changed to `nil`. I want to know which code does the change. What should I do?

By the way, I've already tried `debug-on-variable-change`, but strangely, the debugger was not shown when I switched from an `el` file to an `org` file(that is, when the value of `truncate-lines` was changed from `t` to `nil`).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an active debugger session (`*Backtrace*` buffer) already, preventing a new one from happening?

Comment: Or... when you say "switched from an el file to an org file", you don't just mean changing between two pre-existing buffers, right?  That won't set the variable (both of the buffer-local values would already have been set).